# How to disable native Microsoft Edge tooltips of required inputs?

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I am wondering how I can disabled native tooltips for required inputs in Microsoft Edge?

Here is an example of such a tooltip:

[image]

Comment: This will help you to get your answer in detail http://developer.telerik.com/featured/building-html5-form-validation-bubble-replacements/

Comment: Why do you want to disable the tooltips?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just stumbled across it myself and the link in @Khurram's comment doesn't help with the actual tooltip. The code there removes the speech bubble when you click on a submit button in a form with an invalid input field.

To remove the tooltip, simply add [novalidate to the surrounding form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-novalidate). In browsers other than Edge or IE, you could also add `title=""` to the input field.